# How to enable SharedArrayBuffer and Cross Origin Isolation on Gitlab Pages

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, godot, godot4

I am developing a game in Godot and using Gitlabs CI/CD system and for the game to run I need to enable SharedArrayBuffer and Cross Origin Isolation.

I have searched around but could not find anything to solve this problem